# Method not allowed(#405)

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

following code throws out error like this:
"Method Not Allowed (#405)
Method Not Allowed. This url can only handle the following request methods: ."

Any ideas,how to fix this?

```
    ['label' => 'Logout', 'url' => ['/site/logout'], 'linkOptions' => ['data' => ['method' => 'post']]],
```

Here is still method in SiteController:

```
    public function actionLogout() {
    Yii::$app->user->logout();
    return $this->goHome();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use data-method in linkOptions

```
['label' => 'logOut',
   'url' => ['/site/logout'],
      'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
    ],
```

notice:check behavior in  sitecontroller

```
  public function behaviors() {
        return [
            'access' => [
                'class' => AccessControl::className(),
                'only' => ['logout', 'dashboard'],
                'rules' => [
                    [
                        'actions' => ['logout'],
                        'allow' => true,
                        'roles' => ['@'],
                    ],

                ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'logout' => ['post'],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
```