# S3 hosted React app gets 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router, serverless-framework, http-status-code-405

I have a react app hosted in S3. It is behind a Cloudfront CDN, which is reachable via a custom domain:

`console.example.com -> CDN -> S3 hosted app`

I also have a serverless application acting as my backend to handle API calls from the React app. This is also behind a Cloudfront CDN, which is reachable via a custom domain:

`api.example.com -> CDN -> API Gateway`

The front end is correctly configured to point to `api.example.com`. For the API Gateway, CORS is enabled.

When I navigate to the home page and attempt to login, `console.example.com/login`, I get the `405 Method Not Allowed` error. Login, obviously using `POST`

I verified that the following curl is successful, when hitting the backend via API Gateway endpoint, Cloudfront Domain and the custom domain, effectively ruling out any API Gateway issue.

curl:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"email":"name@test123.com","password":"xyz"}' \
  https://api.example.com/login
```

In my research, I have found that S3 does not support `POST`. I have also found similar questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44860332/method-not-allowed405) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414609/react-app-hosted-on-aws-s3-api-requests-fail), which were not helpful in my case unfortunately.

It is also worth noting that running my frontend and backend locally, works just fine, leaving me to think the S3 issue is my blocker here. But I'm not sure why. My `POST` endpoints are not trying to POST an object to the S3 bucket, they should be using the bundle.js file to hit the api endpoint.

So what am I missing? While I am not a frontend specialist, I assume others host react apps on S3 and can hit their api's just fine no?

I have intentionally not included the code as there would be a lot to digest there but am happy to include any that would be helpful, such as serverless.yml files or cloudformation templates etc. Any help would be awesome.

**** UPDATE - Added Cloudformation template for frontend Cloudfront CDN ****

```
Distribution:
Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
Properties:
  DistributionConfig:
    Origins:
      -
        # Use the Website as the origin
        DomainName: !GetAtt 'Website.DomainName'
        Id: !Ref Website
        CustomOriginConfig:
          HTTPPort: 80
          HTTPSPort: 443
          OriginProtocolPolicy: https-only
    Enabled: true
    HttpVersion: http2
    DefaultRootObject: index.html
    CustomErrorResponses:
      - ErrorCode: 404
        ResponseCode: 200
        ResponsePagePath: /index.html
      - ErrorCode: 403
        ResponseCode: 200
        ResponsePagePath: /index.html
    DefaultCacheBehavior:
      AllowedMethods:
        - DELETE
        - GET
        - HEAD
        - OPTIONS
        - PATCH
        - POST
        - PUT
      DefaultTTL: 60
      ForwardedValues:
        QueryString: true
        Cookies:
          Forward: none
      # The origin id defined above
      TargetOriginId: !Ref Website
      ViewerProtocolPolicy: "redirect-to-https" # we want to force https
    # The certificate to use when using https
    Aliases: 
      - console.example.com
    ViewerCertificate:
      AcmCertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:11111111:certificate/11111111-fa9b-4705-b9d2-11111111
      MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1
      SslSupportMethod: sni-only
```

Comment: Have you allowed the POST method in the API gateway Cloudfront distribution?

Comment: @cbr I believe all methods are allowed. I tested hitting the API Gateway directly, and the CDN domain and the custom domain, all return as expected. Its when the request comes from the frontend

Comment: Are you using IAM authentication?

Comment: @cbr I am using Cloudfront Access Identity. I have attached the Cloudformation template for reference

Comment: Yes, but probably not using IAM on the API distribution then?

Comment: @cbr No, I am not. I dont recall any documentation mentioning IAM to setup Cloudfront/S3 origin

Comment: @cbr your comment got me thinking, and then I came across this doc that shows POST is not supported using OAI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html#private-content-origin-access-identity-signature-version-4
So I updated to use `CustomOriginConfig` instead. But now its still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think that's related since you make the POST request to the API Gateway cloudfront distribution, and not to the S3 distribution. Just to verify, the frontend makes a POST to api.example.com and not to console.example.com/login?

Comment: @cbr the browser console shows 405 is related to console.example.com/login, I presume because it's trying to access the login route, which should then call the api. Sorry for being unclear there.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53939779/996081) or [this](https://apimeister.com/2017/05/09/hosting-a-cloudfront-site-with-s3-and-api-gateway.html) help?

Comment: @cbr I'll give the second one a shot, though I dont see how it resolves the issue. Having both origins in the same CDN seems nice but wont react router still be an issue? I honestly cannot believe this is an issue given the growth of react and serverless in general

Comment: I added 405 to `CustomErrorResponses` and now I get a 403 issue. I think Cloudfront is not forwarding Authorization header and query strings

Answer (score 0):

I updated CustomErrorResponses to include 405 and I no longer get "405 Method Not Allowed" error:

```
CustomErrorResponses:
  - ErrorCode: 405
    ResponseCode: 200
    ResponsePagePath: /index.html
  - ErrorCode: 404
    ResponseCode: 200
    ResponsePagePath: /index.html
  - ErrorCode: 403
    ResponseCode: 200
    ResponsePagePath: /index.html
```